# Usuário votou negativo na minha resposta para subir a própria resposta. O que a moderação pode fazer?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Olá!

Primeiro, não estou acusando ninguém. Mas me surgiu esta dúvida recentemente em uma situação que poderia ser caracterizado desta maneira: o usuário votou negativo na minha resposta para destacar mais a resposta dele. Vejam o cenário:

Um usuário fez uma pergunta de resposta relativamente simples. Fui um dos primeiros a visualizar e enviei a resposta ao mesmo tempo que outra pessoa. Quase que no mesmo segundo que publiquei, recebi um voto negativo (sem justificativa), o que fez com que minha resposta descesse entre as respostas disponíveis, ganhando menos destaque.

Não vou denunciar o usuário pois não tenho certeza que foi isto mesmo, mas me pergunto se a moderação tem ferramentas para identificar estes comportamentos.

Comment: Como você mesmo disse, não tem como saber se foi isso. E não tem o que fazer. Nem mesmo a moderação tem como saber, isso teria que entrar no cérebro da pessoa para saber porque ele votou. Um CM poderia ver quem votou ali se for informado pra ele a situação. Mas isso ainda não garante o motivo do voto, e duvido que seria feita uma avaliação sem ter um indício mais forte. Esses dias anda tendo votos aleatórios por causa dos chapéus.

Comment: E digo mais, não tem nada a ver com chapéu votar negativo.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo aí só quem votou negativo mesmo pra saber. Mas eu concordo com ser uma teoria válida.

Comment: É que no site da WinterBash não tem nenhum chapéu que você ganhe por dar votos negativos. Acho que nem mesmo os secretos.

Comment: Existe o que tem de pior, o chapéu secreto que ninguém sabe qual é o critério e aí a pessoa fica tentando qualquer coisa pra ver se ganha um atavio. Se o critério é secreto, só tentando para descobrir.

Comment: Pensei em fazer uma denúncia para deixar a moderação "esperta" com o usuário, mas como disse, acho injusto se eu estiver enganado, pois estaria mais para "suspeita". Creio que se ele for denunciado mais algumas vezes, seria indício suficiente da má prática do usuário. Como eu não denunciei, posso estar prejudicando esta descoberta da moderação com relação a possível má conduta do usuário. Sobre os chapéus, não sabia que estava este hype todo na busca deles.

Comment: Sem confissão, não tem como saber. Já tive um caso parecido, mas o próprio usuário acabou confessando e os votos foram revertidos.

Comment: Acho besteira se encafifar com essas coisas, se você deu uma resposta objetiva, clara, concisa , e correta, é o que importa pra comunidade, se a resposta é idêntica, nesse caso, pra evitar confusão eu até apagaria a minha resposta.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio concordo plenamente, inclusive em relação a apagar a resposta para evitar confusão. Neste momento eu estou tentando ganhar reputação pois existem privilégios que acredito serem necessários para que eu possa ajudar mais (sendo assim, ficaria chateado com uma situação citada no post), pois meu intuito é realmente ser mais um usuário ativo na comunidade para que eu possa auxiliar no crescimento, e tenho certeza que precisarei de muita ajuda aqui também!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os moderadores não tem acesso a esses dados, mas o programador do site pode ter acesso. Pelo que entendo de postagens dele por aqui no meta, é uma questão de ética e também por experiência própria dele, o trabalho que se tem com isso não vale a pena. Obviamente só dará atenção a casos realmente graves.

Nesse caso específico que abordaste, que aliás é recorrente, mesmo que prove a ação ainda terá que provar a intenção. Ou seja, é algo inviável pois depende de confissão da pessoa ou testemunhas confiáveis. Percebe como é complicado? Agora imagine ter que atender a todas as ocorrências de milhares de usuários. Comigo isso acontecia bastante até eu atingir mais de 10 mil pontos. O nível de pontuação ajuda um pouco a afastar esses tipos de pessoas mas ainda assim acontece exporadicamente.

Há uns 3 dias atrás aconteceu comigo mas foi vacilo meu. Postei uma resposta de um tablet e não percebi que publiquei faltando uns 2 parágrafos. Editar de um tablet é meio complicado pois o site não possui um suporte adequado para telas touch (teclado virtual). Enquanto editava, deve ter apagado sem querer e ficou uma informação errônea. Tomei 2 negativos. Corrigi a resposta, alertei 3 vezes aos que negativaram mas infelizmente não tomaram atitude de remover os negativos e comentários. Vejo eles ativos em outras postagens o que quer dizer que devem ter visto a notificação do meu comentário. E pior, positivaram em respostas rasas ou mesmo errôneas. Prefiro também não expor o caso aqui. Hoje não ligo para isso, mas quando estava começando no site eu me estressava com essas mediocridades e fui pecebendo que os moderadores não tomam atitude em relação a esses assuntos como acontece em foruns. Então aqui é sempre melhor manter o foco no que postou, fazendo uma boa formatação e com conteúdo consistente.

Estressando com isso você só perde tempo e energia. E quem foi anti-ético, também não ganha nem perde nada. Apenas infla o ego temporariamente. No dia seguinte nem lembra mais do que fez. E enquanto isso você fica criando mágoa ou desenvolvendo uma úlcera ou, coisa pior. kkk.

## O que fazer?

Apenas formate bem as suas postagens e deixe que o tempo traga respostas. Você vai ver que com o tempo as pessoas positivam o que estiver melhor.

Claro que nem sempre será perfeito assim e acontecerá injustiças. Nesses casos, apenas tolere e siga em frente.

Dica: Sempre que postar algo, revise o que postou para não dar chances de um medíocre negativar. E mesmo que alguém aponte uma falha, não discuta. Edite e avise que melhorou o conteúdo. Aí nesses casos depende da ética da pessoa que negativa. Boa parte desses não dão a mínima importância. Eles negativam e desaparecem mesmo que você corrija o conteúdo, dando a impressão de que não querem remover o negativo ou simplesmente por esquecerem. Por fim, não podemos julgar mesmo em casos evidentes.

Comment: "*mas o programador do site tem acesso*" - Não exatamente. Os Community Managers tem acesso a isso. Ou seja, o Gabe. Talvez o JNat quando/se o Gabe não puder.

Comment: @VictorStafusa *Tecnicamente*, a resposta é "todo funcionário da SO que trabalha na parte de produtos".

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Também já me aconteceu o mesmo várias vezes mas deixo a pergunta:

O que é mais importante, votos ou aprender e resolver os problemas?

Por mim, podem votar sempre negativo desde que eu consiga a informação que procuro e possa com isso ajudar outros.

Comment: Não é bem por aí. Se você tem um trabalho de fazer uma boa resposta e te  derem muitos negativos, qualquer um que, à primeira vista, ver uma resposta negativada, vai achar que tem algo errado e ignorar. Os votos são qualitativos no site (ou pelo menos deveriam ser). É claro que se você tem um voto negativo contra dez positivos, podemos afirmar que o negativo não faz diferença alguma.

Comment: Concordo que não se deve ter uma preocupação excessiva com votos, mas não se preocupar nada não é o caminho. A maioria deles quer dizer alguma coisa. Isso é um indicativo que a pessoa está fazendo algo errado e seria bom rever a [help] e aprender o site de uma forma melhor e caprichar mais nas perguntas e principalmente nas respostas que podem estar ensinando errado. Se a pessoa achar que negativos não significam nada vão continuar fazendo tudo errado e isso não é nada desejável.  Mesmo um negativo isolado pode significar algo importante.

Comment: É raro as pessoas negativarem algo. É mais raro negativarem sem motivo, ainda que acontece mesmo. Tente entender porque está recebendo negativos, aprender e melhorar.

Comment: Opinião não é um facto mas a minha opinião é que os votos só servem para Marketing... se vocês acham que os votos servem para o que disseram, então nesse caso o site deveria ter webmasters qualificados a classificar as perguntas e respostas. E não, os votos não são raros. Se fossem não havia pessoas a queixarem-se, correcto? Ora veja, o comentário que fiz foi algo negativo? Acho que não mas houve alguém que deu voto negativo? Porquê? Eu só disse que aprender é mais importante do que ter votos.

Comment: Desculpem, até podem dar 100 votos negativos mas a minha opinião é que os votos só servem para colocar os usuários todos os dias a fazerem log in.... Psicologia amigos.... Quem realmente se interessa por aprender só olha para isso mesmo, aprender, partilhar e ajudar, com votos ou não. Mais uma vez, é só a minha opinião. Se não concorda, pode dar voto negativo, eu deixo ;-)

Comment: "votos só servem para colocar os usuários todos os dias a fazerem log in.... Psicologia". Exato. A maioria das respostas são dadas por usuários ativos e engajados no site. Os votos é um sistema de "gamificação" que incentiva as pessoas acessarem todos os dias. Sem sistema de votos, com pessoas apenas procurando respostas duvido que SO estaria onde está.

Comment: Eu fico incentivado e motivado é quando aprendo e partilho o que aprendo... :-) Deveria haver webmasters qualificados para darem votos caso contrário isto até parece politica... é ganhar votos lol

Comment: @Murilo eu não poderia falar melhor. Se não fossem as pessoas qualificadas que respondem aqui ninguém ia aprender nada. O sistema foi bem pensado para fazer tudo funcionar. Não é perfeito, mas funciona. De forma utópica não funcionaria. Votar tem importância fundamental para funcionar e classificar conteúdo. Alguns entendem isso e colaboram, outros não querem dar algo tão simples de volta por terem recebido conhecimento. E todos aqui aprendem todos os dias com todo conteúdo.

Answer (score 3):

O que fazer se um usuário **clicou errado na setinha pra baixo** e depois quis clicar na setinha pra cima?
Atualmente o site só permite após uma edição do conteúdo.

Comment: Já vi acontecer. É um problema, embora normalmente se ele não percebe na hora, dificilmente vai perceber depois.

Comment: Você tem um intervalo de tempo para consertar isso. Só trava depois de alguns minutos

Answer (score 3):

Mesmo que a moderação não faça, não é muito saudável votar contra só por birra ou para promover a própria resposta. **Quem faz isso também perde pontos:**

> **O que acontece quando eu voto contra?**
>
> Ao votar contra, você joga esse conteúdo para o final da página, de modo que ele será visto por menos pessoas. Votar contra respostas é algo que não queremos que você faça de forma leviana, por isso não é gratuito.
>
> - Os votos contra removem 2 pontos de reputação do proprietário da  publicação.
> - Os votos contra respostas removem 1 ponto de sua reputação, o votante.
> - Os votos contra perguntas são gratuitos. (Por quê?)
> - Você pode votar 30 vezes por dia UTC. Você obtém 10 votos a mais somente para perguntas. (Por quê?)

[veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Não é muito, ou não é de forma nenhuma? :) ... Sim, o fato que devem sempre levar em conta é votar pelo conteudo da postagem e não pela pessoa que postou, tanto downvotes quanto upvotes ;)

Comment: Quando o motivo da votação é só a birra, não é de forma nenhuma. Quando a birra tem fundamento técnico, não é muito.

Comment: Eu não estou falando de birra, eu estou falando do comportamento esperado/desejado/saudavel para comunidade ;). O saudadevel é sempre votar pelo qualidade e utilidade da postagem e nunca porque você gosta ou desgosta de uma pessoa.

Comment: "Birra" é sinônimo de "teimosia". Nem toda teimosia pode ser considerada insalubre. Alguma teimosia pode vir acompanhada de comportamento esperado/desejado/saudavel para comunidade ;)

Comment: Independente do significado, o que eu quero dizer é que a birra tem que ser sobre a postagem e nunca sobre sua afinidade com o autor.

Answer (score 2):

Todo mundo já comentou sobre o quão difícil é identificar intenção de casos isolados, e realmente é basicamente impossível que os moderadores possam descobri o motivo de um caso isolado. O trabalho é quase sempre feito baseado em padrões.

O SOpt funciona sob o princípio de não presumir malícia. São dezenas de milhares de usuários, centenas de posts e milhares de votos todos os dias. Com tanta coisa acontecendo, sempre vão haver casos que te deixam com uma pulga atrás da orelha, e quase todos são apenas consequência do volume, aliado à propensão humana a falhar. Por isso padrões são nossa maior arma.

Dito isso, a moderação sempre dá uma olhada nas coisas quando somos avisados... Vai que é a primeira evidência de algo maior?

Mas ao avaliar esse caso, eu sequer consegui encontrar a situação que você descreveu. O downvote mais rápido que você já recebeu foi pouco acima de 1min, numa pergunta que sequer tinha alguma outra resposta.

Todos os outros downvotes aconteceram mais de 1 dia após seu post e mais da metade deles foi eventualmente removido.

**Não gostaria que você apontasse nomes, ou links**. Raramente isso é necessário no Meta. Mas, com as informações que você passou, devo dizer que não encontro nada que justifique sua preocupação. O que é uma ótima notícia.

Answer (score -1):

As pessoas estão achando que isso aqui é Like e Dislike.. ah gostei dessa pergunta "like" ah não gostei "dislike" já vi vários disso.. pois muitas perguntas contundentes e fundamentadas sofreram unvote e outras sem muito a acrescentar sofreram o voto bom.. me leva a crer que não estão sabendo fazer o bom uso da ferramenta.

Comment: Acho que você é quem não compreendeu a filosofia do site e o funcionamento do mesmo. Nada a ver comparar o recurso do facebook com os daqui.

Comment: A maior parte dos downvotes é justos sim, só uma pequena minoria é por rixas, ou mal entendimento. O downvote é usado para avaliar um conteúdo com problemas.

Comment: Agora me diga recebi -3 votos com base no meu comentário ou seja se a pessoa gostou ou não do que eu disse, concorda comigo que foi um dislike? isso prova exatamente o que eu disse só não ver quem não quer.

Comment: Primeiro, os downvotes no meta não afetam a reputação. Segundo, eu não posso afirmar a motivação dos downvotes, mas não é por dislike e sim para mostrar que tem algo errado no **seu** entendimento. Eu só estou tentando lhe orientar ;)

Comment: Fale por vc eu tinha 28 de reputação e agora tenho 25... isso é fachada e hipocrisia todo mundo vota como quer... só porque eu não entendi da mesma forma que a sua não quer dizer que eu esteja errado tão pouco justifica o seu voto negativo.. sou responsável pelo que digo não pelo que entende... para mim os votos aqui são igualmente do Facebook.

Comment: O seu comentário anterior mostra o quanto você tem compreensão da filosofia do site :)

Comment: Antes dos downvotes eu tinha visto sua resposta, estava 25, só no site principal o downvote afeta, está claro que você está confundindo algo do funcionamento do site. Veja que alguém mais lhe deu um downvote e continua 25pontos.

Comment: @RenatoAssis deve entender que voto negativo serve principalmente pra alertar a quem fez a pergunta/resposta/comentário que há alguma coisa de errado.... "No mundo perfeito.." seria que todos votos negativos viessem acompanhados de um comentário de quem votou explicando o que viu de errado, de modo que a pessoa pudesse editar a pergunta/resposta, e quem votou negativo viesse e retirasse o voto negativo..... claro que em vias de regra isso as vezes não ocorre....

Comment: @RenatoAssis o site não é o facebook, o voto negativo é uma ferramenta usada para classificar o conteúdo do site bom/ruim, se vc recebeu votos negativos é sinal de que há alguma coisa errada com sua postagem, edite ela e procure sempre deixar mais claro, assim diminui as chances de vc receber votos negativos.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio se for assim eu concordo em base no assunto/conteúdo voltado a comunidade como um todo, de que vale negativar sem mesmo esboçar a sua reação e a que o levou a realizar? vou apenas dizer que não concordo e não me justifico? vou negativar a sua pergunta com seu código sem dizer o que esta errado? sem isso não vejo qualquer valia da ferramenta... ou seja volto meu argumento inicial.. estão fazendo mau uso da ferramenta.

Comment: @gato não esta certo.. como vou revisar e saber onde esta errado só porque fui negativado? deveria ser obrigado antes de negativar vc justificar o seu voto negativo para então a pessoa que postou a pergunta possa entender se não de nada vale o recurso.

Comment: Quanto ao mau uso da ferramenta eu não discuto pois concordo, mas é uma minoria. Agora usar disso para comparar com o facebook é uma demonstração de total desconhecimento do funcionamento do SO.

Comment: @RenatoAssis nem todo mundo tem uma reação positiva quando sabe quem negativou, justificar o voto é complicado, tem usuários que não sabem lidar com criticas e leva para o lado pessoal e devido a isso age de forma grosseira e de forma rude.

Comment: @RenatoAssis sobre o mau uso, existem casos em que isso ocorre, mas é minoria como disse o Diego, e se tem provas de que estar recebendo votos negativos de forma indevida basta postar aqui no meta.

Comment: @gato então quer dizer que o certo é negativar sem mesmo mostrar o erro? não acho funcional.

Comment: Um detalhe importante, se você votar negativo em uma resposta, você próprio perde "reputação".... sempre acreditei e acredito ser um recurso que afasta as pessoas de saírem negativando tudo que veem pela frente

Comment: @RenatoAssis as pessoas geralmente não justificam devido ao mesmo pensamento que você teve no começo, a pessoa dá o downvote e comenta o motivo, o autor da pergunta ou resposta que recebeu o downvote não entende bem o significado, mesmo explicando (quase sempre acontece), leva a mal e começa a negativar as publicações de quem negativou e justificou, como um tipo de retalhação. Você pode argumentar que você não irá fazer isso, mas não tem como saber quem terá esse tipo de atitude, então por isso a ferramenta é feita para ser anonima, para evitar "brigas" e "ataques gratuitos".

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio isso é interessante, mais o certo seria doutrinar toda a comunidade a realizar as funções de acordo com as regras... uma alternativa disso é monitorar efetivamente esses votos e o que os levou... vou negativar uma pessoa porque escreveu o código errado? ou devo orientar? o recurso negativar serve como sinalizador? se a pessoa lhe der o código <titlee>teste</title> ela deve ser negativada? acredito que quem responder a pergunta de forma errada merece ser negativado nesse caso é apenas orientação é o meu ponto de vista.

Comment: @RenatoAssis por isso existem os tópicos de ajuda [tour] [answer] [ask] entre tantos outros, complicado doutrinar iniciantes se eles não se dispuserem ao menos a entender como funciona a comunidade

Comment: @diegofm não vou me dispor a lhe responde, me perdoe a ignorância não sou muito adepto a hipocrisias.

Comment: Não precisa, meu ponto de vista já ficou bem claro e confirmado com todos os seus comentários seguintes ;)

Comment: @RenatoAssis como doutrinar todo mundo? É impossível, entenda uma coisa, não tem como os moderadores e staff conhecerem todas linguagens e tecnologias para determinar que o voto mal usado, o máximo que podemos fazer é orientar. O primeiro site da rede SE foi criado em 2008, são 9 anos de ideias, problemas, tentativas de melhoria, a ideia de deixar os votos anônimos é algo que foi muito analisado e repensado...

Comment: ...Não adianta chegar aqui e afirmar que você acha que melhor é X, sendo que tem várias pessoas que já pensaram e estudaram qual o melhor em anos, não será uma conversa de minutos que vai determinar que a sua ideia é o melhor caminho.

Comment: @diegofm o seu ponto de vista é o "seu" ponto de vista assim como é a "minha" opinião.

Comment: A rede SE possui [**inumeros sites**](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) sob essa filosofia de gamificação, e todos estão ai em auge e funcionando perfeitamente. Até para se criticar é preciso conhecer sobre o que se está criticando, senão sua critica é vazia e sem sentido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então quer me dizer que devo aceitar o fato que o meu Pais esta indo por um caminho correto em vista que tem numa sala mais pessoas a favor disso do que eu contra? #planalto isso esboça a sua opinião e me desculpe me parece que vc esta um tanto alienado.

Comment: @diegofm assim como qualquer voto negativo, como o seu por exemplo... de que vale uma critica construtiva que não agrega nada?

Comment: @RenatoAssis se uma critica é construtiva no minimo alguma coisa agrega, mas depende da pessoa para e refletir ;)

Comment: Quais provas você tem de que eu votei negativo em algum post seu?

Comment: @RenatoAssis não é uma sala, não é apenas a Staff, é algo dedico pela maioria nas comunidades, não foi uma decisão politica e ela já foi repensada varias vezes, aqui a Staff não ganha nada com ups e downvotes, portanto ninguém decidiu que esse é o melhor "visando lucros", pois para ele é indiferente. Como eu disse, e não leve a mal, você realmente não entende o funcionamento e como as comunidades chegaram até aqui.

Comment: Eu que não vou mais perder tempo discutindo isso aqui com alguém criticando algo que nem sequer entende o real funcionamento e os motivos deste funcionamento. E nem procurou saber, pelo visto.

Comment: @diegofm usei como exemplo, se vc votar negativo terá obrigatoriamente de mostrar e dizer porque o fez se não apenas mostra que vc gostou ou não gostou certo? o Facebook de Portugal usa para o nome Like e Dislike a palavra Gosto = Like para mim ainda estou no mesmo entrave... bom quanto a critica pode se vim de qualquer lado mais não agrega nada do que o próprio ponto de vista de quem o fez.. palavras vazias.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parei de ler nos lucros sem +.

Comment: @diegofm faz muito bem, todo aquele que quer que os entenda mesmo no fato de não o entender se ausenta mostra que é tão leigo ao assunto quanto arrogante de querer fazer, entender aquilo que "vc" quer... ou seja egoísta e nada maleável.. você não tem como dizer que alguém sabe ou não alguma coisa, não esta na cabeça de ninguém para dizer tal afirmação, e voltando a minha resposta a traz você esboça e representa apenas a sua opinião então preste bem atenção antes de querer que todos aceite aquilo que vc quer. Eu abordo o assunto de forma que "acho melhor" não que quero que seja assim.

Comment: @RenatoAssis entenda que a Stack Overflow é uma empresa, o qual possui 3 sites com mesmo nome (incluindo pt.stackoverflow.com), por isso citei lucros. Isso só mostra mais como você não entende o que é o site, nem como ele funciona e nem como as coisas foram decididas para chegar a este "ideal". Apenas por isso citei lucros para que você entenda que a Staff da empresa decidiu anonimato nos votos para o bom funcionamento da comunidade e que eles não ganham nada com isso. Por favor pare de pensar de maneira pessimista e entenda a minha boa vontade em lhe orientar.

Comment: Quem afirmou que `não estão sabendo fazer o bom uso da ferramenta`, mas nem sequer a entende não fui eu ;)

Comment: Cada um vota como bem entende (afinal é secreto)... Muitos sem responsabilidade, outros entendem e usam corretamente, mas ao meu ver o problema dessa sua resposta é que vc está fazendo uma analogia com outra ferramenta que não representam a mesma coisa, isso pode não ser bem visto, por alguns... Relaxa man, downvote sobra pra todo mundo...faz parte...

Comment: @diegofm esta bem sem + isso não vai levar a lugar nenhum continue negativando os membros da comunidade sem mesmo dizer a eles onde estão errando... use a ferramenta e entenda como quiser o seu real interesse.. eu tenho uma madeira faço dela um barco vc pode fazer uma canoa mesmo material opções diferentes.

Comment: @MagicHat eu sei que não são a mesma coisa, mais se votar quer dizer gostar é o mesmo que curtir é o mesmo ponto de vista.

Comment: @RenatoAssis no caso de upvotes até acontece e no caso de downvotes realmente algum maus usuários, ou que não entendem o sistema acham que esse é uso, mas quem participa ativamente, geralmente entende e os ups e downs desses usuários ativos geralmente são justos, o motivo de não justificar eu já lhe expliquei ;)

Comment: Não creio ser uma questão de gostar ou não , aqui é mais uma questão de certo e errado mesmo...são coisas diferentes no face tem muito like em coisa errada, aqui pode começar mas depois reverte, esses dias mesmo respondi recebi -3 (em uma resposta controversa) e já to com +4... a comunidade vê tudo

Comment: @MagicHat certo ou errado em que conceito?

Comment: Como assim ? aqui 1+1 = 3 recebe downvote no face pode receber like...sacou ?

Comment: @MagicHat agora você entrou no assunto que estou falando.. aqui nesse debate abaixo da minha resposta tem vários votes que na minha opinião é gostei da sua resposta e da sua opinião ou vai dizer que não? ou eles recebeu voto porque escreveu com uma boa ortografia? o voto foi de forma positiva ao comentário de fato um "gostei" da sua resposta... mais é claro nem todos usam assim.. assim como o autor do tópico teve 16 votos que de fato se resulta como positivo ao argumento ou positivo ao comentário? a favor? gostei do que disse? curti isso? gosto disso? palavras diferentes mesmo intuito só ver.

Comment: Cara com todo respeito, o que acho que não está entendendo é que não é questão de gosto e sim que o raciocínio pode estar correto... são coisas diferentes... Hoje vc tá muito pilhado com isso talvez vc ache que alguns não entendem seu ponto, eu entendo, e embora não negativei, acho que está errado (mas posso dizer que gostei da sua resposta, mesmo estando incorreta na analogia)... Com o tempo se vai ver as coisas diferentes....Just relax... coloca uma resposta maravilhosa é no fim coloca "aqui no fórum" se vai ver o que acontece

Comment: Só acho que o downvote não deveria ser aplicado "acho, ACHO".. ´ porque vc não concorda o outro não deve ser prejudicado, apenas teria a opção de votar a favor ou simplesmente não ter votos, não ter reconhecimento ou seja não tem credibilidade esse seria o ideal "downvote" assim como conheço algumas outras comunidades developers que não adotam esse recurso, espero de verdade que possa entender através do meu ponto de vista... vou terminando por aqui desculpa qualquer coisa a todos.. opiniões e debates assim caminhamos para frente, seja pela direita ou para esquerda.. de fato ainda caminhamos.

Comment: veja o que aconteceu com esse fulano :http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5497/chap%C3%A9us-sapatos-roupas-usadas-quem-tem-2016#5507
a resposta poética, mas nos detalhes fugiram da pergunta... E olha que eu conheço muito dos que deram negativos, nem por isso vou falar que tão errado, isso é comunidade, nem tudo segue nossas próprias opiniões

Comment: @MagicHat deveria ser a mesma função dos comentários ter opção somente de votar a favor, assim não prejudica quem perguntou ele não ganhará nada (votos positivos) e não perderá nada (votos negativos) com isso perde-se sua credibilidade, se tivermos realmente o intuito de ajudar iremos lhe responder a forma que ele deve abordar a questão assim ele poderá abrir novos tópicos de forma clara, sem problemas algum.

Comment: discordo, quando postam bobagens, é devido a essa ferramenta, que se impede de propagar o erro ao leigo....votos injustos acontecem, mas se for um usuário que posta respostas boas a comunidade reverte... se eu vejo um negativo injusto além de comentar o pq do negativo eu positivo na hora...

Comment: @RenatoAssis O que você ainda não entendeu é que UpVote e DownVote não serve para expressar sentimento emocional em relação à publicação. O SO não é Facebook porque no Facebook as pessoas votam pelo emocional, pelo coração. Aqui não existe emoção, existe apenas a razão, os votos devem ser feitos pelo conteúdo técnico da publicação. Isso quer dizer que se você postar algo tecnicamente errado, irá receber downvote. Se você postar algo tecnicamente certo irá receber upvote, independente de ortografia ou organização do texto (desde que isso não atrapalhe no entendimento da publicação, é claro)

Comment: @RenatoAssis Você pode ver que o UpVote e DownVote possuem legendas, basta manter o mouse em cima deles e verá sua razão de uso. No caso de perguntas: UpVote: `Esta pergunta mostra esforço de pesquisa; é útil e clara`. DownVote: `Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara e não é útil`. E no caso de respostas: UpVote: `Esta resposta é útil`. DownVote: `Esta resposta não é útil`. E o UpVote dos comentários: `Este comentário adiciona algo útil à publicação`. Ou seja, não tem nada de "gostei" ou "não gostei". Os votos aqui no SO são puramente técnicos.